# looking for pac4j with javax servlet with java 17

Tags: pac4j

I am trying to use pac4j for my oidc implementation with javax.servlet based we application which already have database authentication .
Is there any version which is compatible with java 17 and javax.servlet. and by when i should expect in production. or java17 will be delivered with jakarta.servlet only.

thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, pac4j is agnostic from any implementation. So you should be able to use the OIDC support with javax or jakarta in pac4j v6 / JDK 17.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jlelu ,i can see RC versions are release till now ,by when the final release is expected . am kind of struggling to find correct compatible version of my case which is to use additional ( optional ) OIDC authentication along with existing database authentication which is securing all my rest endpoints .my application is javax.servlet based with java 17 . i was trying to follow this https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j  samples but could not get the correct compatible version to get this working .is there any other demo app to use with pac4jv6  please advise.

Comment: The final pac4j v6 release is "blocked" by the final OpenSAML v5 release. I hope at the end of this year.